# bonobo git server iis installation error

Tags: asp.net, git, iis, bonobo

```
    Server Error in '/Bonobo.Git.Server' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:


Line 68:       </namespaces>
Line 69:     </pages>
Line 70:     <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 71:   </system.web>
Line 72:   <system.webServer>


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\web.config    Line: 70

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927   `
```

I tried to install the bonobo git windows based server and did as they said in the install guide. But getting the above error . help me solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the app pool to run as .NET 4.0. You can see in your error that the .NET framework 2.0 is currently configured:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927

Comment: How to change the app pool to run .net 4

Comment: In the IIS manager (available from Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager), click on "Application Pools" , and change the settings for the application pool you're using (e.g. DefaultAppPool): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx (also see http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12).